# MySQL Trigger auto increment

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'd like to create a mysql(v5.5) trigger which performs auto increment by a random number each time I insert a value. Here is what I am doing:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS actCodeAuto
$$
CREATE TRIGGER actCodeAuto BEFORE INSERT ON activity
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE newNumber INT DEFAULT 1;
  SELECT Max(activityCode) INTO newNumber FROM activity;
  IF(newNumber=NULL) THEN
    SET new.activityCode=100;
  ELSE
    SET new.activityCode = newNumber+FLOOR(1+RAND()*3);
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I want to auto increment a random number to the max value of column `activityCode` each time I insert a row, except when I insert a row for the first time, I want to set Max(activityCode) to 100.

While I insert a row for the first time, MySQL just reports an error: **(1048, "Column 'activityCode' cannot be null")**

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null is not equal to null in SQL.

So this will never be true:

```
IF(newNumber=NULL) THEN
```

You need:

```
IF(newNumber IS NULL) THEN
```

Comment: I've figured it out! Thanks!